# Antergos Dual Boot - Bootloader Device Selection on Advanced Installation Mode

Tags: partition, dual-boot, boot-loader, antergos

I am trying to install Antergos alongside an existing Windows 10 installation following [this guide](https://antergos.com/wiki/install/how-to-dual-boot-antergos-windows-uefi-expanded-by-linuxhat/)

I configured my partitions as per the guide, but as I have multiple drives I'm unsure which device to select for installing Grub2, Therefore I am still at the partition stage of the setup, until I know what I'm doing!

My devices are as follows:

```
/dev/nvme0n1    500GB M.2    Existing Win 10 install
/dev/sda          1TB HDD    Storage
/dev/sdb        128GB SSD    Antergos Installation (Currently an old Win10 install I want to erase)
```

And are partitioned this way:

```
Device          Type   Mount point   Label     Size
===================================================
/dev/nvme0n1p1  ntfs                 Recovery  523M
/dev/nvme0n1p2  fat32  /boot/efi     ESP       104M
/dev/nvme0n1p3  ?                               17M
/dev/nvme0n1p4  ntfs                 Windows   499G
---------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1       ntfs                 Storage     1T
---------------------------------------------------
/dev/sdb1       ext4   /             Antergos   20G
/dev/sdb2       swap   swap          Swap        8G
/dev/sdb3       ext4   /home         Home       98G
```

Only partitions on `dev/sdb` are marked to format.

I currently have `Grub2` and `Unknown [500GB] (/dev/nvme0n1)` selected for the bootloader installation options.

Thanks in advance!